# Mimicking TOCTOU in Go

Tags: vulnerability

I'm trying to simulate a race condition in Go to replicate a time-of-check time-of-use vulnerability (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use). The code below takes in a user-provided fruit and searches for it in an array. If the fruit is found it returns the name of the fruit:

```
package main

func check(fruit string) string {
    fruits := []string{"apple", "banana", "orange", "peach"}

    found := make(chan bool)
    go func() {
        found <- contains(fruits, fruit)
    }()

    if f := <-found; f {
        return fruit
    }
    return "Not found"
}

// Check if fruit belongs to fruits slice.
func contains(fruits []string, fruit string) bool {
    for i := range fruits {
        if fruits[i] == fruit {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Test:

```
package main

import (
    "testing"
)

func TestCheck(t *testing.T) {
    fruits := []string{"starfruit", "apple"}

    for _, fruit := range fruits {
        res := check(fruit)
        if res != "apple" {
            t.Errorf("got: %s, want: %s", res, "apple")
        }
    }
}
```

Essentially, I'd like the test to FAIL - e.g. it manages to return "starfruit" 100% of the time with the vulnerability unpatched. What would be the best way to do this? I'm unsure the best way of demonstrating it with my current test.

Comment: Perhaps, it's because I'm not familiar with go, but I can't see the "vulnerability" in here.

Comment: If you want it to fail *100% of the time* you will need to edit the code such that there's an explicit ordered execution between the check and the use. Otherwise, you'd have a race condition, where it may or may not fail depending on the vagaries of the scheduler. Also, though: I'm not super familiar with golang, so maybe I'm missing something, but you don't seem to be doing anything to invalidate the check result. If you don't do that, there can't be a TOCTOU risk.